# How to optimize the dynamically generated Join query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I am researching on **Query Optimization for Dynamically generated Join Queries in SQL Server**.

Suppose I have huge database which contains 10-15 tables containing 1000 of users. When I create a join query dynamically, we don't to the best order in which we can **join** so that we get the output in optimized way or in minimum time.

**Consider a scenario:**

Suppose I want to create join query which **requires 8-10 tables** (out of 10-15 tables present in database) containing thousands of records. So how can we arrange the sequence of joining the table dynamically in join query so that we get the optimized result?

Is there any way to breakdown the query and join the results of those queries **or** some other way which can give us best result for **dynamically** generated join in SQL Server **or** some dynamic way through which we can decide the best order of joining the tables.

Please reply me...

Thank you ...

Comment: You could force order of joins, but as with all hints you should know what you are doing. Would you care to post the actual query and explain why do you think it's performing badly? BTW, 15 tables with thousands of records is not a huge database.

Comment: Its not necessary that database has thousands of records it might contains any no.of records depending on no.of users using it.Actually I create the query 'Dynamically' ,so i want to know what factors are there which affects the query execution performance.I mean how we can plan for join query for multiple tables that will give us optimized result.

Comment: Generally query performance depends mostly on the structure and size of your tables and how they are indexed. You should generate your query in most straightforward way and let the database engine decide in what order it wants to join the tables. If you have performance problems investigate what's wrong and add/remove indexes as needed.